# Error when loading library even library loaded

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I'm now updating my company's old CI2 Website to CI3. Model, Controller and View from the CI2 seem to work fine after a little bit changes but my app keep showing "**Fatal error: Class 'CI_Func' not found in pathtoapp\system\core\Common.php on line 196**" when load library, the "**Func.php**" with "**F**" is capitalization, it's location is in "**pathtoapp\application\libraries**" and just echo "Hello world" for testing purpose. The text "Hello world" showing up but the app still showing the error. I've tried many other libraries but it just showing the same kind of error like "Fatal error: Class 'CI_Someotherlibrary'...". My system is running using IIS, PHP 5.5 and MySQL.

Here is my Func.php and my controller

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Func {
function __construct()
{
    echo 'Hello world';
    }
}

class Home extends CI_Controller{
public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();      
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->load->helper(array('url', 'form', 'download', 'text', 'views'));
    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $this->load->Model("Menus");
    $this->load->Model("2019/News","News");
    $this->load->library('Func');
}}
```

I don't know why it keep adding "**CI_**" before my library name. I'm still new with CI and new to stackoverflow too. I've already search over internet and try almost everything but still no luck. Any advice will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.
PS: Sorry for my bad English.

update infomation from @Bira quest
- When i change the name of class to CI_Func or $this->load->library('func');, the new error coming up: "An Error Was Encountered Unable to load the requested class: Func"

Update 1:
Here is two threads that nearly like my issue but can't solve my problem
[Thread 1](https://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-62387.html)

[Thread 2](https://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-62310-post-320133.html#pid320133)

Update 2:
- I figured it out that when i'm not using $this->load->view in my Views, the error disappear. May be the cause is $this->load->view trigger something that make loader class went wrong. I just don't know what wrong with it because i'm using $this->load->view to load some part of my website layout and it worked fine with CI2. Someone help me, please.

Update 3:
- I've solved it. In my view, i create new instance of the controller using like $home = new home(); so may be it load the library again and cause the error. Thank you all for your helps.

Comment: download a fresh CI3 framework and copy your MVC folders. that is the easiest way.

Comment: @Bira I downloaded fresh CI3 and using model, controller and views with some config in routes.php, config.php, constants.php and database.php just to run the app . I've tried 3 times, each time i copy, change a little to find out which files may cause the error but the results still the same.

Comment: `library ` method should extends a current any of CI library. your class is not extending any. https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html

Comment: @Bira I'm sorry for not providing this information, i'll update the post. When i change it to CI_Func, the new error coming up: "An Error Was Encountered Unable to load the requested class: Func". Thanks

Comment: $this->load->library('func'); // no caps, try this. Class name is fine, no need CI_

Comment: @Bira i've already tried $this->load->library('func'); and try using autoload too but still no luck, the error just "Unable to load the requested class: Func". It's very weird.

Comment: @Bira As I read the docs and try to using it on original CI3 framework, it just work fine even my class doesn't extends any CI library. Is there any problems can cause by change configs in routes.php, config.php, constants.php?

Comment: Library is independent class, it should not extend any predefined class. Please share Func class code to help further.

Comment: @SangitaKendre The code of Func class is in the post. It just echo "Hello world" and it work but app still display error about "CI_Func".

Comment: can you write a simple method on it ?

Comment: @Bira Yes, if write a function like **public function hello() { echo 'Hello world 2019'; }** and using it in controller like $this->func->hello(); The app display text "Hello world" and "Hello world 2019" and the app showing error: **Fatal error: Class 'CI_Func' not found in pathtoapp\system\core\Common.php on line 196**  line 196 in Common.php is **$_classes[$class] = isset($param)
   ? new $name($param)
   : new $name();**

Comment: Bira, SangitaKendre: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it. In my view, i create new instance of the controller using like $home = new home(); so may be it load the library again and cause the error. It's hard to trace the error. Thank you all for your helps.